# Validation Groups for FormType - Issue Work-Around

Tags: php, symfony

I am refering to a missing feature in Symfony: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3622

I have several entities that have a OneToOne-relation to an `Address` entity. All these OneToOne-relations come alongside the constraint `@Valid()`. Consequently, I have an `AddressFormType` that is embedded in other forms. Sometimes the addresses in the various forms are required and sometimes they are not.

**Problem**

Even when I have a validation group defined in the entity `Address`, it is not possible to pass this validation group along using the following code:

```
$builder->add('address', AddressFormType::class, array(
    'required' => true,
    'validation_groups' => array('required'),
));
```

Now, until Symfony 3.0.0 adding a `cascade_validation` could fix this problem. Unfortunately, `cascade_validation` was removed in Symfony 3.0.0 and no solution for the problem at hand was provided.

**Possible Work-Around**

It is possible to disable the validation for the `address` field all together and simply validate it in the controller. However, due to the fact that I am using the FOSUserBundle combined with the PUGXMultiUserBundle, that would be an enormous work-around for such a little problem.

**Question**

Are there any alternatives to validate the addresses properly?

Comment: As I understand you want to disable `Address` entity validation for some forms? Or for some validation groups?

Comment: @KamilAdryjanek The input should be validated everytime. The only difference is that sometimes there is an additional NotBlank-Assert for the validation group 'required'.